Coins Not Moving to Canvas Position When Camera Moves
I am currently developing a 2D game in Unity, and I'm having an issue with moving coins to a specific position in the UI Canvas when they are spawned. I want the coins to animate from their spawn position in the game world to a point in the Canvas. However, when the camera moves, the coins do not correctly reach their destination; they seem to go off-screen.
Here is the context of my issue:
Setup:
I have a CoinManager script that is responsible for spawning coins and animating them to the UI Canvas.
The coins are instantiated at a position based on the player's interactions, and I want them to move to a fixed position in the Canvas when collected.
The Code:
Here is the relevant part of my CoinManager script:
public class CoinManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CoinManager instance;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject coinPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Transform coinParent;
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform coinEndRectTransform; // The target point in the Canvas
    [SerializeField] private int maxCoinAmount;
    [SerializeField] private float coinPerDelay;
    [SerializeField] private float moveDuration;
    [SerializeField] private float totalDelay;
    [SerializeField] private Ease moveEase;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed()
    {
        int coinAmount = Grave.Instance.GetCurrentCoins();
        coinAmount = Mathf.Min(coinAmount, maxCoinAmount);
        coinPerDelay = totalDelay / coinAmount;

        for (int i = 0; i < coinAmount; i++)
        {
            var targetDelay = i * coinPerDelay;
            ShowCoin(targetDelay);
        }

        Invoke(nameof(OnAnimationDone), totalDelay + moveDuration);
    }

    public void OnAnimationDone()
    {
        Grave.Instance.UpdateCoinText();
    }

    public void ShowCoin(float delay)
    {
        GameObject graveObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Grave");

        if (Grave.lastGraveWithCoins != null)
        {
            var coinObject = Instantiate(coinPrefab, coinParent);
            var offset = new Vector3(Random.Range(-.5f, .5f), Random.Range(-.5f, .5f), 0f);
            var startPos = Grave.lastGraveWithCoins.transform.position + offset;
            coinObject.transform.position = startPos;

            // Calculate the position in world space for the coinEndRectTransform
            Vector3 worldPosition;
            RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(
                coinEndRectTransform,
                coinEndRectTransform.position,
                Camera.main,
                out worldPosition
            );

            // Scale the coin before moving
            coinObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.1f, .1f, .1f);
            coinObject.transform.DOScale(Vector3.one, delay);

            // Move the coin to the calculated world position
            coinObject.transform.DOMove(worldPosition, moveDuration)
                .SetEase(moveEase)
                .SetDelay(delay)
                .OnComplete(() =>
                {
                    coinObject.SetActive(false);
                });
        }
    }
}

Issue:
The main problem I am facing is that when the camera moves, the coins do not reach the designated position in the Canvas correctly. They sometimes go off-screen or do not move to the intended point.
I need the coins to always animate toward the fixed position in the Canvas, regardless of the camera's position or movement. I suspect that there may be an issue with how the position is calculated or applied, especially when the camera is not stationary.
Additional Information:
The coinEndRectTransform is set up in the UI Canvas, and it should represent the target position where I want the coins to go.
The game is using Cinemachine for camera control, and I'm not sure if this affects the behavior of the coins.
I would appreciate any insights or alternative methods to ensure the coins always animate to the correct position in the Canvas, even if the camera moves.

If you calculate a fixed point in the world as the correct position where it looks like it is correct, as soon as you move the camera the world position stays the same but that point does not allign anymore with your canvas position since the canvas does not move.

@agone The code is calling ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle once before the animation starts; it is not updated continuously.

@kevin, That is why I posted a comment, Either it is moving when it shouldn't or not moving when it should. The question did not indicate if the target position is supposed to be attached to the camera.

Thank's for the feedback, I could not get back to you until today. I got the solution in the answer

I've implemented a solution that continuously updates the target position during the animation. This way, even if the camera moves, the coins correctly align with the UI, ensuring smooth movement toward the end point.
public void ShowCoin(float delay)
{
    GameObject graveObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Grave");

    if (Grave.lastGraveWithCoins != null)
    {
        var coinObject = Instantiate(coinPrefab, coinParent);

        var offset = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f), 0f);
        var startPos = Grave.lastGraveWithCoins.transform.position + offset;
        coinObject.transform.position = startPos;

        coinObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.1f, .1f, .1f);
        coinObject.transform.DOScale(Vector3.one, delay);

        StartCoroutine(MoveCoinToUIDynamically(coinObject, delay));
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveCoinToUIDynamically(GameObject coinObject, float delay)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    Vector3 startPos = coinObject.transform.position;
    float duration = moveDuration;

    while (elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 screenPos = coinEndRectTransform.position;
        Vector3 worldPosition;

        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(
            coinEndRectTransform,
            screenPos,
            Camera.main,
            out worldPosition))
        {
            coinObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, worldPosition, elapsedTime / duration);
        }

        yield return null; 
    }

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(
        coinEndRectTransform,
        coinEndRectTransform.position,
        Camera.main,
        out worldPosition
    );
    
    coinObject.transform.position = worldPosition;
    coinObject.SetActive(false);
}

